# how do I get foreighkey of foreighkey without a loop in django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

It is a Django project, I am trying to create a wishlist (many-to-many will not help because I need DateTime of getting that wished item in the wishlist).

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField()

class WishItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name="wishlist", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    added_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

What I could do is only this:

```
wishlist = Client.objects.wishlist.select_related('product').all()
wish_products = [item.product for item in wishlist]
```

But I need something like this, without a loop but with a single SQL query and single line

```
wishlist = Client.objects.wishlist.product.all()
```

When I try to run this code I get an error **AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'product'**

Comment: `Product.objects.filter(wishitem__client__user=my_user)`.

Comment: Ok, but it will not be ordered by added_at field

Comment: `Product.objects.filter(wishitem__client__user=my_user).order_by('wishitem__added_at')`.

Comment: NameError: name 'wishitem__added_at' is not defined

Comment: it is within quotes, so `'wishitem__added_at'`, not `wishitem__added_at`.

Comment: Hello @deepdows I am not getting what exactly you are looking for. So you want all the product list related to Client Wishlist right?. correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: Willem Van Onsem already answered my question. I need all products on the wishlist that is related to the client. it could be done with many-to-many, but I want to know what time it was added to order it by this datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) and then [**`.order_by(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) with:

```
Product.objects.filter(wishitem__client__user=my_user).order_by('wishitem__added_at')
```

You can make it more covenient to query by spanning a `ManyToManyField` with your `WishItem`:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    # …
    wishlist = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Product',
        through='WishItem'
    )


class Product(models.Model):
    # …
    pass

class WishItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name='wishitems', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    added_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

then you can query with:

```
Product.objects.filter(client__user=my_user).order_by('wishitem__added_at')
```

It will also make querying for the `.wishlist` of the `Client` more covenient, of the `Product`s where the `.client_set` is a manager that manages the `Client`s that have that `Product` on the wishlist.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Answer (score 1):

Many to many relationship will fix the problem you can add extra fields to your WishItem class you can try this :

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField()

 class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    WishProducts = models.ManyToManyField(Product,through='WishItem')


class WishItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    added_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Django will not automatically add `ForeignKey`s in the through model: it will construct a model with these `ForeignKey`s if you do not define one, but if you manually specify a `through` model, you should define the `ForeignKey`s yourself.

Comment: Yes i am sorry, i confused that, i edited my code